# Testing XPages with Selenium IDE

Tags: xpages, selenium-ide

I wanted to create a demo of using Selenium within XPages development. So demo 1 would be to start using the Selenium IDE and the playback tool but I quickly ran into the problem that when I use a namespicker (bootstrap enabled) it could not playback the highlighted name in the namespicker.

So I am wondering, how useful is this Selenium IDE for XPages developers anyway?

Comment: DOM-based automation has often (always?) problems with namespicker or date picker dialogs. One solution is to use a visual test solution like [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) or [SeeShell](https://a9t9.com/seeshell/web-automation).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you end up writing Selenium scripts (in JavaScript, Java or Python). You might want to checkout UiLicious as an alternative. It is almost like writing English sentences.